# file_put_contents duplicating content

Tags: php, apache, file, fwrite

I am using `file_put_contents` writing to a file and I'm getting duplicate content ... written 2x and 1x litura

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test.tmp', '1 ', FILE_APPEND);
```

contents of test.tmp

> 11

already restarted apache and I am accessing directly without htaccess.

Comment: Are you calling it twice? Have you already called it once and did it again?

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` for reading and `file_put_contents` for writing. Also FILE_APPEND mode appends the new content to the previous one. Empty your file, then retry.

Comment: forgiveness friends, I duplicated when written. file_put_contents is only one that duplicates the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `file_put_contents` in *Append* mode so 1 will be appended every time you run the script. Use the code without 3rd parameter.

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test.tmp', '1 ');
```

Now the output of the `test.tmp` file will always be 1.

Comment: FILE_APPEND is not the problem, it just overwrites what already exists

Comment: FILE_APPEND is the problem. It appends the new content to the previous one.

Comment: FILE_APPEND will not overwrite what already exists. It will append the new value to the previous one. Here is a good explanation about FILE APPEND http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileappend.php